# Reverse engineer ip-cam api for movement

Tags: javascript, python, http-post, wireshark, ip-camera

i am currently trying to reverse engineer an ip camera api, because there is not fitting documentation. Therefore I installed the a software for moving the camera (IPCams, Appstore) and installed Wireshark.

While moving the cam by the software, the following http post-requests appear from my laptop to the camera:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shwir.png)

Can anyone tell me how to reengineer this request?

Thanks and BR
Jan

Comment: That's a SOAP request. Familiarize yourself with the protocol. I wish you Good Luck, you will need it!

Comment: Thanks, after rebuilding the request in Insomnia it finally works :)